# PHP: NULL value in an ARRAY stored as a string in a table

Tags: php, arrays, database, null

Ok. So I have a form that's supposed to get user info, including ethnicity info which is supposed to be stored in an array to allow multiple selections, but it's also supposed to be optional so that no one is obligated to make any selection

input page
    Ethnic Background (Choose all that apply):

```
  <input type="checkbox" name="ethnicity[]" value="Indian"> American Indian or Alaska Native<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="ethnicity[]" value="Asian"> Asian<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="ethnicity[]" value="African-American"> Black or African-American<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="ethnicity[]" value="Pacific"> Native Hawaiian or other Pacific Islander<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="ethnicity[]" value="White"> White<br>
```

on my processData page everything is then stored into variables

```
$email = filter_input (INPUT_POST, 'email');
$passwordUser = filter_input (INPUT_POST, 'passwordUser');
$phone = filter_input (INPUT_POST, 'phone');

$sex = filter_input (INPUT_POST, 'sex');
if ($sex == NULL) {
    $sex = 'unknown';
}

$age = filter_input (INPUT_POST, 'age');
$state = filter_input (INPUT_POST, 'state');

$ethnicity = filter_input (INPUT_POST, 'ethnicity', FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS, FILTER_REQUIRE_ARRAY);
if ($ethnicity !== NULL) {

}  else {
     'No answer selected.';
}
 include 'insertData.php';
```

and on the insertData page all of the info is then inserted into the tables.

```
include 'database.php';

try {
$query = "INSERT INTO accounts
            (ageGroup, emailAddress, gender, password, phoneNumber, stateAbbr)
          VALUES
            (:ageGroup, :emailAddress, :gender, :passwordUser, :phoneNumber, :stateAbbr)";

$statement = $db->prepare($query);
$statement->bindValue(':ageGroup', $age);
$statement->bindValue(':emailAddress', $email);
$statement->bindValue(':gender', $sex);
$statement->bindValue(':passwordUser', $passwordUser);
$statement->bindValue(':phoneNumber', $phone);
$statement->bindValue(':stateAbbr', $state);
$statement->execute();
$statement->closeCursor();


foreach ($ethnicity as $result) {
    $query = "INSERT INTO customerethnicity
            (emailAddress, ethnicity)
          VALUES
            (:emailAddress, :ethnicity)";

    $statement = $db->prepare($query);
    $statement->bindValue(':ethnicity', $result);
    $statement->bindValue(':emailAddress', $email);
    $statement->
    execute();
    $statement->closeCursor();
}
echo "Account created successfully!";
    } catch (PDOException $e) { //Catches and handles db errors to prevent site crash

    $title = 'Error';
    $caption = 'System message:';
    $message = $e->getMessage() . '<br><br> An error has occurred. Please check the information entered and try again.';

    include 'Database_error.php';
```

The database uses two tables linked by the email and the email and ethnicity together create new rows on the table designed specifically for ethnicity. The other table stores the rest of the info. Everything ALMOST works. I can have the gender blank and it stores 'unknown' in the table, but I cannot leave the ethnic boxes unchecked and have a similar 'unknown' value inserted into the table in place of NULL without getting this message:

> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\xampp\htdocs\FormData\insertData.php on line 26

```
Account created successfully!
```

this is on line 26: `foreach ($ethnicity as $result) {`

The Account created successfully tester message pops up and if I look in the table I can see that all the other info entered shows up in the accounts table, but nothing shows in the customerethnicity table. If I fill out the info or even if I leave other values blank and only select one or more ethnicitys then everything works. The issue is when no ethnicity is selected. I need to have a value show up in denoting that nothing was selected.

Comment: Question: If only 1 ethnicity is selected: Will it still be an array?

Comment: If only 1 is selected, it shows up correctly in the customerethnicity table with the email and the one selection both appearing on the same row. If there are multiple selections then there are multiple rows that share the same email. The problem, is that if there are no selections everything still runs, but I get the warning message and no entry of any kind is made in that table. The other is fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Appologies for the delay, but ultimately the solution that I ended up using was this:

```
$ethnicity = filter_input (INPUT_POST, 'ethnicity', FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS, FILTER_REQUIRE_ARRAY);
if ($ethnicity !== NULL) {


}  else {
    $ethnicity = array('unknown');
}
 include 'insertData.php';
?>
```

Posting this in the hopes it may prove beneficial to someone else.

Answer (score 0):

Have if condition for unset case, add ID for the check boxes and have something like that:
`if (document.getElementById('yourCheckBoxID').checked) {
            alert("checked");
        } else {
            alert("Please check");
        }`

Comment: "but it's also supposed to be optional so that no one is obligated to make any selection"

Comment: @VolkerK Hmm in that case I think he need's Group of Radiobuttons not Checkboxes.

Comment: Using radio buttons because some people identify with multiple ethnicities, and for those that wish to identify it has to be an option. It is meant to allow the option of having no ethnic groups selected or one or more selected. Radio button does not provide that flexibility. That's why it's within a foreach loop. So that each selection can appear attached to the same user email on individual rows if more than one is selected.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply test whether `$ethnicity` "is" an array before trying to iterate it.

```
if ( is_array($ethnicity) ) {
    $query = '
        INSERT INTO customerethnicity
            (emailAddress, ethnicity)
        VALUES
            (:emailAddress, :ethnicity)
    ';

    $statement = $db->prepare($query);
    $statement->bindParam(':ethnicity', $result);
    $statement->bindParam(':emailAddress', $email);

    foreach ($ethnicity as $result) {
        $statement->execute();
        ...
```

[sscce](http://sscce.org/):

```
<?php
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test;charset=utf8', 'localonly', 'localonly', array(
    PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES=>false,
    PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_DIRECT_QUERY=>false,
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE=>PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
));
setup($pdo); // creating temporary tables for the example

// the array is more or less what you got from your filter_input script
// doInsert will extract it, so the code in that function looks like your second script
doInsert($pdo, array(
    'age'=>'21-39',
    'email'=>'emailA',
    'sex'=>'m',
    'passwordUser'=>'1234',
    'phone'=>'5678',
    'state'=>'neverneverland',
    'ethnicity'=>['de','fr','au']
));

doInsert($pdo, array(
    'age'=>'80+',
    'email'=>'emailB',
    'sex'=>'m',
    'passwordUser'=>'abcd',
    'phone'=>'9876',
    'state'=>'midleearth',
    'ethnicity'=>null
));

// example for querying the data
// not sure if that's a really good way to do it; but ...just an example ;-)
showUser($pdo, 'emailA');
showUser($pdo, 'emailB');

function doInsert($db, $params) {
    extract($params);

    try {
        $db->beginTransaction(); // that should answer your second question, see http://docs.php.net/pdo.transactions
        $query = "
            INSERT INTO soFoo
                (ageGroup, emailAddress, gender, password, phoneNumber, stateAbbr)
            VALUES
            (:ageGroup, :emailAddress, :gender, :passwordUser, :phoneNumber, :stateAbbr)
        ";
        $statement = $db->prepare($query);
        $statement->bindValue(':ageGroup', $age);
        $statement->bindValue(':emailAddress', $email);
        $statement->bindValue(':gender', $sex);
        $statement->bindValue(':passwordUser', $passwordUser);
        $statement->bindValue(':phoneNumber', $phone);
        $statement->bindValue(':stateAbbr', $state);
        $statement->execute();
        $statement->closeCursor();

        if ( is_array($ethnicity) ) {
            $query = '
                INSERT INTO soBar
                    (emailAddress, ethnicity)
                VALUES
                    (:emailAddress, :ethnicity)
            ';

            $statement = $db->prepare($query);
            $statement->bindParam(':ethnicity', $result);
            $statement->bindParam(':emailAddress', $email);

            foreach ($ethnicity as $result) {
                $statement->execute();
            }
        }

        $db->commit();
    }
    catch(Exception $e) {
        $db->rollBack();
        throw $e;
  }
}

function showUser($db, $email) {
    $statement = $db->prepare('
        (
            SELECT
                ageGroup,gender,stateAbbr
            FROM
                soFoo
            WHERE
                emailAddress=:e1
        )
        UNION ALL
        (
            SELECT
                ethnicity,null,null
            FROM
                soBar
            WHERE
                emailAddress=:e2
        )
    ');
    $statement->bindValue(':e1', $email);
    $statement->bindValue(':e2', $email);
    $statement->execute();

    $user = $statement->fetch();
    if ( !$user ) {
        echo 'no user with email=', $email, "\r\n";
    }
    else {
        printf("%s %s %s\r\n", $user['ageGroup'], $user['gender'], $user['stateAbbr']);
        $eth = $statement->fetch();
        if ( !$eth ) {
            echo '  unknown ethnicity';
        }
        else {
            do {
                echo '  ', $eth['ageGroup'], "\r\n";
            }
            while( ($eth=$statement->fetch()) );
        }
    }       
}


function setup($pdo) {
    $pdo->exec('
        CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE soFoo (
            id int auto_increment,
            ageGroup varchar(32),
            emailAddress varchar(32),
            gender varchar(32),
            password varchar(32),
            phoneNumber varchar(32),
            stateAbbr varchar(32),
            primary key(id),
            unique key(emailAddress)
        )
    ');

    $pdo->exec('
        CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE soBar (
            id int auto_increment,
            emailAddress varchar(32),
            ethnicity varchar(32),
            primary key(id),
            unique key(emailAddress, ethnicity)
        )
    ');
}
```

prints

```
21-39 m neverneverland
  au
  de
  fr
80+ m midleearth
  unknown ethnicity
```

Comment: would that allow me to actually put a string into the table in place of NULL so that an entry appears attached to the email in order to show no selection was made?

Comment: @VolkerK  the insert statement shouldnt it be after the foreach?

Comment: Yes, when you query the ethnicities and no record is returned add whatever string you like instead. In case you're querying the data from all the tables in one query using a JOIN, use a LEFT JOIN and check for a NULL value in the ethnicity field.

Comment: @Thomas: no, the statement should be prepared just once, before the foreach loop. The parameter :email is also set only once before the foreach loop (so bindValue would probably do; I just didn't want to mix bindValue and bindParam) and the other parameter :ethnicity is bound to $result which is set by the foreach loop and then the statement gets executed.

Comment: The purpose of the foreach is to allow each ethnic selection to be attached to the email it's associated with and placed on separate rows if multiple ethnic selections are made.

Comment: Yes, the code does that. That's what prepared statements + (named) parameters are for: prepare once, use multiple times with varying parameters.

Comment: @Kr4ckl3s if we take this answer here your "nothing selected part" would be an insert statement in the else part of the if where you need to fill in whatever you want to instead of the true ethnicity.  Although in that case the whole insert itself should be consid3ered to be put outside the if and $result set in the else path to whatever you want to insert in that case.

Comment: Somehow inserting that piece of code almost worked, except that it broke the catch block designed to put up a message in plain english explaining that there was a duplication error in the event the form is resubmitted or something of that nature.

Comment: That's a different problem/question.

Comment: Got it. Although it still doesn't place a value into the table. No warning message, but equally no data in the customerethnicity table if no boxes are checked.

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
if(isset($_POST['ethnicity'])){

    foreach ($ethnicity as $result) {

    ....
    }
}
```

Comment: A little explanation would be nice.